# Backbone JS event functions modify object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am working on a fairly complex application with BackboneJS. I have a Globals object that I use to publish/subscribe to events. The challenge is that it doesn't seem like there is an efficient means to decouple the functions using event-driven architecture.

I am thinking of more of an eventing system like Magento. You see, in Magento, you call `dispatchEvent`, and pass along an object. The next line in Magento (which would be breaking, meaning, it's waiting for all subscribers to that event to execute first), you can access those objects again. The nice thing with this way is that any function that subscribes to the event is passed an object that it can modify, and then return that object.

So, when the subscribers have finished executing, we can take this modified object and finish execution. In JS, that would be a callback, but the idea is the same.

So my questions:

- Are you aware of anything like this baked into Backbone?
- Are there plugins that you know of?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own events and pass whatever parameters to the event handlers that you want. For example, you can define an event and pass an object when triggering that event:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    go: function() {
        var o = { };
        this.trigger('some:event', o);
        console.log(o);
    }
});
```

and then the listeners can stash whatever they want in the object they get as an argument:

```
var m = new M;
m.on('some:event', function(o) {
    o.where_is = 'pancakes house?';
});
m.on('some:event', function(o) {
    o.ill_cook = 'you some eggs, Margie';
});
m.go();
```

That will leave you with `{where_is: 'pancakes house?', ill_cook: 'you some eggs, Margie'}` in `o` when you hit the `console.log` call in `go`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4XCmc/

The standard Backbone events have their own specified argument lists for the listeners of course but you can add whatever custom events you need.